# WPF - Button not change content property value based on binding context

Tags: .net, wpf, vb.net

In my code-behind constructor, I set data context to anonymous type:

```
Class MainWindow
  Sub New()

    ' This call is required by the designer.
    InitializeComponent()

    ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
    Me.DataContext = New With {
      .theTrigger = "trigger value"
    }
  End Sub
End Class
```

And in my xaml file, the `Button` should change its content to custom value based on `theTrigger` property above. Button only `TextBlock` content that change. This is the xaml:

```
    <StackPanel>
        <Button>
            Init
            <Button.Style>
                <Style TargetType="Button">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding theTrigger}" Value="trigger value">
                            <Setter Property="Content" Value="Triggered!" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Button.Style>
        </Button>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding theTrigger}" />
    </StackPanel>
```

Comment: `<Button>Init ...` sets a so-called local value for the Button's Content property. This has higher precedence than the value from the DataTrigger Setter, hence the DataTrigger is ignored. Add another Style Setter for the initial Content.

Comment: Yup.. Thank you very much.